# Bitwise operation susceptible to fail at runtime typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, bit-manipulation, operation

`This conversion may fail at runtime ..`

```
crc=~crc.
```

I cannot tell why.

Here is the code:

```
function CRC_Check_Pol(data_byte_array : char[], crc_bytes :  char, DATA_BYTE_SIZE : Number)
{
  /*CRC - 8*/
  var crc :char;
crc=0xFF;
var byte_indx; //index for data_byte_array


for ( byte_index=0x00; byte_indx< DATA_BYTE_SIZE; byte_indx++){ 
            crc = table[(data_byte_array[byte_indx] ^ crc)]; 
} 

crc = ~crc;
```

I will include the lookup table if its necessary (it is an array of bytes in hex).

I would be glad if you can give me hints what could cause the compile error.

Comment: ~ is Unary bitwise complement. It is JS. Well, it will be. Typescript output is a JS.

Comment: There is no 'char' type in TypeScript. At the top you say this "may fail at runtime" without defining what 'fail' means, then later you say this is a "compile error". Which is it? What's going on? What's the actual behavior and what's the expected behavior?

Comment: The compiler states this : This conversion might fail.
 Char type is recognized and used as such, though I am not so sure there is a char type in Typescript. 
  Although, I have found the problem, and yes, it was using char type instead of byte. 
Please Ryan compose your asnwer here so I can appreciate it:)

Comment: It sounds like you're using JScript, not TypeScript? There is no `byte` type in TypeScript either.

Comment: Indeed, I was confused about these 2 languages, sorry if I mislead all of you. 

Though how can this be that : Typescript has a javascript output, and cannot support byte or char types (just primitive types)?

Is this worth a question to make officially? I really want to reward your implication in my ungrounded question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments you seem to be under the impression Javascript has BYTE and CHAR primitive types and therefore TypeScript should have them.

Javascript only has `number` `string`, `boolean`, `array`s and `object`'s (and `undefined` & `null` if you want to get technical). [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

TypeScript is just doing lots of nice compile-time checking for you (and providing various coding shortcuts). You need to find equivalent methods for doing each step *in Javascript.*

Comment: Down-votes without comment are about as useful as a Chocolate teapot. If you have something to say, say it :)

Comment: Indeed, I take it granted such thing, as my javascript knowledge is rather beginner, coming from the C territories. Thank you for the clarification!